# is there a way to reference svg from page in the css?

Tags: html, css, svg

I see that you can reference the svg by id in some css/svg properties, as in:

```html
<!-- the logo svg -->
<svg id="rect-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- left squares -->
    <rect fill="url(#rect-fill)"/>
</svg>
```

does anyone know if we can use a svg from the page, in a css bg for example? to avoid encoding it on the css.
Something like this, which I already tried but did not seem to work the same way.

```css
.myel {
  background-image: url(#rect-svg-image);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a misconception to clear up.

```
fill: url(#source);
```

does not reference arbitrary SVG content, but a [paint server](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html), namely a gradient or pattern. Other uses of the CSS `url()` notation in SVG include the `clip-path`, `mask` and `marker-start|mid|end` properties that all also can only reference specific elements.

Currently, `background-image` needs an actual self-contained image resource or a [CSS gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient). Referencing a SVG paint server with `url()` does not work.

But the [CSS Images Module Level 4](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-images-4/#element-notation) also defines a [`element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) functional notation that can reference fragments inside the page.

If you look at the text of the specification, there are still a lot of open questions listed to solve before this can become mainstream. There currently is only a Firefox implementation with vendor prefix, `-moz-element()`. You can point it to paint servers; that means you can (mis)use a `<pattern>` element. Although experimenting, I found there are some tradeoffs to make:

- `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` needs all content drawn into a 1px*1px square, but makes the content scalable. Preserving the aspect ratio is not supported.
- `patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` gives you preservation of the aspect ratio, but scaling is not supported.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: -moz-element(#image);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <pattern patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
           width="100%" height="100%" id="image">
    <rect width=".5" height=".5" fill="red"/>
    <rect width=".5" height=".5" x=".5" fill="yellow"/>
    <rect width=".5" height=".5" y=".5" fill="green"/>
    <rect width=".5" height=".5" x=".5" y=".5" fill="blue"/>
    <circle r=".5" cx=".5" cy=".5" fill="white" opacity=".5"/>
  </pattern>
</svg>
<div>
```